# Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException using -query and --as-parquetfile

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, parquet

I am trying to import a table data from Redshift to HDFS (using Parquet format) and facing the error shown below:

```
15/06/25 11:05:42 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:97)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Command line query used:

> sqoop import --driver "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver" --connect
>   "jdbc:postgresql://:5439/events" --username "username"
>   --password "password" --query "SELECT * FROM mobile_og.pages WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by anonymous_id --target-dir
>   /user/huser/pq_mobile_og_pages_2 --as-parquetfile.

It works fine when `--as-parquetfile` option is removed from the above command line query.

Comment: It works fine with --as-parquetfile when we just use --table without --query.

Answer (score 2):

It is confirmed to be a bug [SQOOP-2571](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2571).

If you want to import all data of a table, then you can eventually run such a command:

```
sqoop import --driver "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver" \
  --connect "jdbc:postgresql://:5439/events" \
  --username "username" --password "password" \
  --table mobile_og.pages \
  --split-by anonymous_id \
  --target-dir /user/huser/pq_mobile_og_pages_2 \
  --as-parquetfile
```

And `--where` is also an useful parameter. Check the [user manual](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html).